# React API - В чем разница между синхронности и асинхронности?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, сервер, api, redux

Изучаю React - API, столкнулся с двумя понятиями - синхронность и асинхронность, что такое синхронность и асинхронность? и в чем разница между ними?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748175/asynchronous-vs-synchronous-execution-what-does-it-really-mean можно ассоциировать с этим вопросом с enSO

Comment: Мне в свое время понравился притянутый за уши, но показательный пример, что, если бы наш мир был синхронным. Звонит человек такой в доставку пиццы, заказывает пиццу. Мироустройство заставляет его завершить текущую задачу, поэтому потом он висит на телефоне и отслеживает статус заказа до тех пор, пока доставщик не явится. В асинхронном мире этот человек обычно занялся бы другими делами, пока доставщик сам бы с ним не связался.

Comment: Стоит привести контекст, в котором эти понятия использовались.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React к этому никак не относится, просто код бывает синхронным и асинхронным.

Синхронный код идет по порядку:

```js
const arrOfNumbers = [1, 2, 3];

for (const item of arrOfNumbers) {
  console.log(item);
}

console.log("Выполнение завершено");
```

Как вы видите, "Выполнение завершено" выводится после исполнения цикла.

Что было бы, если бы цикл был асинхронным:

```js
const arrOfNumbers = [1, 2, 3];

setTimeout(() => {
  for (const item of arrOfNumbers) {
    console.log(item);
  }
});

console.log("Выполнение завершено");
```

Как вы можете видеть, "Выполнение завершено" вывелось до исполнения асинхронной функции с циклом. Так как она асинхронная, программа не ждет её исполнения, а идет дальше.

Как эти знания могут пригодиться на практике:

Допустим, нам нужно сделать функцию, получающую посты с сайта и возвращающую их:

```js
function takeData() {
  let data;
  fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => data = res);
   return data;
}

console.log(takeData());
```

В данном случае вернулось `undefined`, так как мы не дождались исполнения асинхронной функции [`fetch()`](https://learn.javascript.ru/fetch).

Вот, как можно это исправить:

```js
async function takeData() {
  let data;
  await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => data = res);
   return data;
}

takeData().then(res => console.log(res))
```

Здесь мы при помощи [`async/await`](https://learn.javascript.ru/async-await) явно указываем, что `fetch()` должна исполниться синхронно.

Ещё можно так:

```js
function takeData() {
  return fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1")
}

takeData()
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(res => console.log(res))
```

Здесь мы просто возвращаем `fetch()`, а уже его обрабатываем вне функции.

Вот полезные ссылки:

- https://learn.javascript.ru/async
- https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function
- https://learn.javascript.ru/async-await

Comment: _Здесь мы при помощи async/await явно указываем, что fetch() должна исполниться синхронно._ - не, тут совсем не это указывается. Наличие async/await в данном случае ни на что не влияет. и вместо него можно было просто возвращать не `data`, а сам результат: `return fetch(...).then(...)`

Comment: @Grundy, действительно можно было бы просто возвращать fetch, но тогда бы это не давало понимания как работать с асинхронными функциями

Comment: тут стоило вообще от `then` было избавиться, чтобы явно было видно, что код стал похож на синхронный. Причем именно похож, а не стал синхронным

Comment: @Grundy, как я могу избавиться от `then`, если async/await возвращает промис?

Comment: речь про `then` внутри функции

Comment: @Grundy, обновил вопрос

Comment: вот тут `then` надо было убрать:   `await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => data = res);`

Comment: а сейчас последний пример совсем не относится ни к вопросу ни к ответу